# Skewness of an Image Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, statistics

Is this the correct way to implement the skewness of an image in java? Please note that I have repeated the same method for Red and Green and I am fully aware of how to bring it all together. I just want to make sure this algorithm is correct before I run this 60 times for my analysis.

It is my understanding that to compute skewness, you simply change the standrad deviation method from the power of 2 in the variance to the power of 3. But it just seems like there should be a little more to it than that. If someone who is more educated than me on this topic could have a look, it would be great. Cheers.

```
    /*Blue Variance*/
    public static double varianceBlue(BufferedImage image){
        double mean = meanValueBlue(image);
        double sumOfDiff = 0.0;

         for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y){
               for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x){
                               Color b = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                               double colour= b.getBlue() - mean;
                               sumOfDiff += Math.abs(Math.pow(colour, 3));
                             }                   
                           }
        return sumOfDiff / ((image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()) - 1);
        }

    /*Blue Standard Deviation*/
    public static double standardDeviationBlue(BufferedImage image){
        return Math.sqrt(varianceBlue(image));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using the RGB color space to analyze an image is not recommended, because the RGB color space is not perceptually uniform space, and its dimensions are highly correlated [Yilmaz, Alper, Omar Javed, and Mubarak Shah. "Object tracking: A survey." Acm computing surveys (CSUR) 38.4 (2006): 13.]. It's better to first convert the image to HSV color space. Secondly, I think it's more common to calculate the skewness of the histogram, not the intensity values, like in [calculate histogram features](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17537-histogram-features-of-a-gray-level-image). To implement it, one can use the definition [skewness](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/moment/Skewness.html).

Answer (score -1):

If you [take a look to this page](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm), you can see that you have to divide by the cube of the standard deviation. There is also an adjusted version of the skewness.

Note the precision about the N value. It's not the same value used to compute the standard deviation and the skewness (N-1 vs N).